# VB.Net, Linq to Xml: Is this the correct way to use logic while creating xml?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

While building an xml document I require to use logic to dictate the outcome of the xml; logically it is similar to the following piece of code (although this does not work):

```
    Dim buildElement As Boolean = True
    Dim xe As XElement = _
    <xml>
        <% If buildElement Then %>
        <BuildMyElement><%= buildElement.ToString %></BuildMyElement>
        <% End If %>
    </xml>
```

I have managed to do this using the method show below, is this the suggested way of doing this or is there a better one??

```
    Dim buildElement As Boolean = True
    Dim xe As XElement = _
    <xml>
        <%= If(buildElement, _
            <BuildMyElement><%= buildElement.ToString %></BuildMyElement>, _
            Nothing) %>
    </xml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use the If clause in one line you have 2 overload that are:

```
 IF(condition, true, false)
```

or

```
 If(Condition,False)
```

You could write something like this to avoid assigning nothing value:

```
If(buildElement is nothing,<BuildMyElement><%= buildElement.ToString %></BuildMyElement>)
```

Comment: Tried that with a nullable boolean but because the two data types are different it produces a conversion error.

Comment: Ok so You have to use your first approach is not a bad solution :)